# html table inside dynamic textarea

Tags: html, flash, html-table, actionscript-2

Is it possible to display an html `<table>` as a table inside an dynamic textarea using `.htmlText` method?

And an additional question: is there any other way to display a table inside a text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textareas are what they are : text areas.
However, it seems to work for basic tables.
I tried something like that with and instantiated a textarea named `toto` :

```
toto.html = true;

toto.htmlText = "<table> <tr> <td> a </td> <td> b </td> </tr> <tr> <td> c </td> <td> d </td> </tr> <tr> <td> e </td> <td> f </td> </tr> </table>"; //spaces seem very important
```

However I have to warn you that text areas are not meant to display full HTML.  Even if they possess some features about it. If you have to display a table it's surely possible to do it differently.

Comment: The above example copied and pasted in Flash CS4 does not work at all. Flash TextFields and Flash TextArea Components do NOT support `<table><tr> or <td>`.